# Text input field "PLACEHOLDER" not appearing

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I'm a newbie, I'm having trouble understanding why the placeholder is not working, I tried using `LABEL` tag but it won't disappear as I start typing into the text input.

I am serving the HTML with express to `heroku`.
here's the code:

```
          <!-- <label for="firstname">FirstName</label> -->
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstname" placeholder="FirstName" required autofocus/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <!-- <label for="lastname">LastName</label> -->
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastname" placeholder="LastName" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <!-- <label for="email">example@gmail.com</label> -->
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" required/>
        </div>
        <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">
          Sign Up
        </button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; Example Inc.</p>
```

edit:
I am using bootstrap for styling and `Express` and `NodeJs` for serving files to the frontend.
here is the overall code for signup page:

```
<link href="../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body class="text-center">
    <main class="form-signin">
      <form method="post" action="/">
        <img
          class="mb-4"
          src="../images/example.png"
          alt=""
          width="72"
          height="57"
        />
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Sign up to my newsletter</h1>

        <div class="form-floating">
          <!-- <label for="firstname">FirstName</label> -->
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstname" placeholder="FirstName" required autofocus/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <!-- <label for="lastname">LastName</label> -->
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastname" placeholder="LastName" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <!-- <label for="email">example@gmail.com</label> -->
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" required/>
        </div>
        <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">
          Sign Up
        </button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; Example Inc.</p>
      </form>
    </main>
  </body>
```

and minimal styling used in stylesheet:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.form-signin {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
}


.form-signin .form-floating:focus-within {
  z-index: 2;
}

.form-signin #firstName {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;

}
.form-signin #lastName {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.form-signin input[type="email"] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

This is how it is displayed on the web app

[image]

Answer (score 1):

can you share some more info, looks like the above is simple HTML, The placeholder will disappear when you edit the input.

Not sure why it wouldn't, perhaps share your code online.

Like [this](https://jsbin.com/nepohiteko/edit?html,output),

```html
<!-- <label for="firstname">FirstName</label> -->
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstname" placeholder="FirstName" required autofocus/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <!-- <label for="lastname">LastName</label> -->
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastname" placeholder="LastName" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <!-- <label for="email">example@gmail.com</label> -->
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" required/>
        </div>
        <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">
          Sign Up
        </button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; Example Inc.</p>
```

where we can inspect and debug it.

As of now, your question is too generic to find the issue. And by looks of class names, you are using some sort of library to style your page. share that info too

Comment: I have edited the ques, please have a look

Comment: Can you add a link for demo? I did checked but its hard to find where is the issue is

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace `form-floating` by `form-group`

```html
<body class="text-center">
  <main class="form-signin">
    <form method="post" action="/">
      <img class="mb-4" src="../images/example.png" alt="" width="72" height="57" />
      <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Sign up to my newsletter</h1>

      <div class="form-group">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstname" placeholder="FirstName" required autofocus/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastname" placeholder="LastName" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">

        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" required/>
      </div>
      <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">
          Sign Up
        </button>
      <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; Example Inc.</p>
    </form>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).